# button submitting not working in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate some process, while I am not able to submit a button in python selenium, this issue is only for this specific URL(https://sitereview.bluecoat.com/#/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:\web driver\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://sitereview.bluecoat.com/#/')

search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("txtSearch")

search_box.send_keys("facebook.com")
search_box.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the parent element of the search field

```
driver.find_element_by_id('searchform').submit()
```

Since the page takes some time to load add explicit wait to wait for the page to load and for the form to be submittable after insertin text

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:\web driver\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://sitereview.bluecoat.com/#/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'txtSearch'))).send_keys("facebook.com")
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#btnLookupSubmit:not([disabled])'))).submit()
# or
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#btnLookupSubmit:not([disabled])'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping,unfortunately still not working

Comment: @AmithP Updated my answer.

Comment: here button is disabled until form element gets filled

Comment: @AmithP Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `click` with webdriver `wait` for element to be `clickable` so element able to receive `click`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "txtSearch")))

element.send_keys("facebook.com")

button= WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnLookupSubmit")))
button.click()
```

**OR (try to click with Java script but without wait as it can be fail on wait, Not a recommended way but works)**

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "txtSearch")))
 element.send_keys("facebook.com") 
    button= driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLookupSubmit")

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping,unfortunately still not working

Comment: Can you try second solution with JS

Comment: @AmithP As i am giving answer from mobile so I could not see source code. I was trying to click on Input field instaed button. i have check source code and I have updated answer too. Hope it will help you now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Action class

```
    submitButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLookupSubmit")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(submitButton)
    actions.click(submitButton)
    actions.perform()
```